# Convert htaccess RewriteCond to web.config

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, web-config

What's the converted/translation of this piece of code from htaccess to web.config?

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think found the answer :

```
    <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members.

If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it.

We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue.

Thanks for your understanding.